# Find duplicate images in fastest way

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, image-processing

I have 2 image folder containing 10k and 35k images. Each image is approximately the size of (2k,2k).
I want to remove the images which are exact duplicates.
The variation in different images are just a change in some pixels.
I have tried DHashing, PHashing, AHashing but as they are lossy image hashing technique so they are giving the same hash for non-duplicate images too.
I also tried writing a code in python, which will just subtract images and the combination in which the resultant array is not zero everywhere gives those image pair to be duplicate of each other.
Buth the time for a single combination is 0.29 seconds and for total 350 million combinations is really huge.
Is there a way to do it in a faster way without flagging non-duplicate images also.
I am open to doing it in any language(C,C++), any approach(distributed computing, multithreading) which can solve my problem accurately.
Apologies if I added some of the irrelevant approaches as I am not from computer science background.
Below is the code I used for python approach -

```
start = timeit.default_timer()
dict = {}
for i in path1:
    img1 = io.imread(i)
    base1 = os.path.basename(i)
    for j in path2:
        img2 = io.imread(j)
        base2 = os.path.basename(j)
        if np.array_equal(img1, img2):
            err  = img1.astype('float') - img2.astype('float')
            is_all_zero = np.all((err == 0))
            if is_all_zero:
                dict[base1] = base2
            else:
                continue
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Comment: "I want to remove the images which are exact duplicates" - There's only one way to do that; compare every byte of every image with every other image. Hash functions *will* have collisions and give you false positives. The *only* way to reliably detect *exact* duplicates of files is to compare them byte by byte (you can make some early checks to speed things up by checking file sizes of course, if two files have different sizes then obviously they cannot be equal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the answer on how to delete duplicate files (not only images). Then you can use, for example, `fdupes` or find some alternative SW: https://alternativeto.net/software/fdupes/

Comment: With any files. It will help to remove absolutely identical files (whatever format)

Comment: I'll check and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: I have used `fdupes` many times to remove duplicate dicom images (format  commonly used in medical imaging).

Comment: The one thing to note is the file must be bit for bit identical. If your files have some difference in the header even with an identical image the file will be seen as different.

Comment: Thank You @drescherjm for the additional input. Is there any other edge case I should be worried about here?

Comment: I don't know of any other problem with this.

Comment: Note that 2 images could be pixel-for-pixel identical but have different size and checksum... if one was TIFF and the other PNG... if the date or comment in the header was different... if they were written by different encoders which use a different compression or strategy...

Answer (score 2):

Use lossy hashing as a prefiltering step, before a complete comparison. You can also generate thumbnail images (say 12 x 8 pixels), and compare for similarity.

The idea is to perform quick rejection of very different images.

Comment: Thank You Yves, though the fdupes approach worked but I am intrigued to learn about your approach too. Could you please elaborate more on how to use lossy hashing as a prefiltering step because it is also including non-duplicate images too.

Comment: @Bing: PREFILTERING.

Answer (score 0):

This code checks if there are any duplicates in a folder (it's a bit slow though):

```
    import image_similarity_measures
    from image_similarity_measures.quality_metrics import rmse, psnr
    from sewar.full_ref import rmse, psnr
    import cv2
    import os 
    import time



    def check(path_orginal,path_new):#give r strings 
        original = cv2.imread(path_orginal)
        new = cv2.imread(path_new)
        return  rmse(original, new)

    def folder_check(folder_path):
        i=0
        file_list = os.listdir(folder_path)
        print(file_list)
        duplicate_dict={}
        for file in file_list:
            # print(file)
            file_path=os.path.join(folder_path,file)
            for file_compare in file_list:
                print(i)
                i+=1
                file_compare_path=os.path.join(folder_path,file_compare)
                if file_compare!=file:
                    similarity_score=check(file_path,file_compare_path)
                    # print(str(similarity_score))
            
                    if similarity_score==0.0:
                         print(file,file_compare)
                         duplicate_dict[file]=file_compare
            file_list.remove(str(file))
        return duplicate_dict
     start_time=time.time()
     print(folder_check(r"C:\Users\Admin\Linear-Regression-1\image-similarity-measures\input1"))
     end_time=time.time()
     stamp=end_time-start_time
     print(stamp)
```